# bootstrap popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure how boostrap implements popover.
I have included bootstrap.js, and it has a function called Popover (upper case P), but in their example, they use:

```
$('#example').popover(options)
```

Now, they say it requires tooltip to be included, but I don't know what that means.
Their examples all include a bunch of .js files and I think in reality they're all packaged up together.

And since I'm at the proof-of-concept phase, where I'm trying to get it to work right the first time, I'm not concerned about the file size or caching.

Comment: Q: When I say: $('#myId').popover(); I get TypeError: $("#myId").popover is not a function.

Comment: If you download the bootstrap-popover.js file the definition of the popover( the function) is defined from line 77.

Comment: Oooohhhh. So I have to include bootstrap.js, bootstrap-tooltip.js and bootstrap-popover.js, all three?

Comment: Yes!!! all three... popover Extends the bootstrap-tooltip. see the line 37 of `bootstrap-popover.js`

Comment: Zoik!  Why couldn't they have included it for us beginners?

Comment: @merv, I thought he had just downloaded the basic css and js functions version of it. As he got a error saying `popover is not a function`

Comment: @uDaY Well, to confound matters, I think earlier releases did NOT include the plugins in the default build, so what you said could very well have been your experience. Anyway, I ended up saying what I wanted to say in the answer I wrote, so I think I'm going to remove the comment, since looking back at it I find it a bit alarmist. ;)

Comment: If you are using bootstrap 3 then bootstrap.min.js is enough to get them worked :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Here's a pretty simple example](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/popover-example.html):

```
<html> 
   <head>
       <link href="http://w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-v2/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="well">
            <a href="#" id="example" class="btn btn-success" rel="popover" data-content="It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover">hover for popover</a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-v2/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
      <script src="http://w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-v2/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
      <script>
      $(function (){
         $("#example").popover();
      });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

The sample includes the tooltip JavaScript that you'll need as well. Just view the source of the page.

Comment: I see that you're using bootstrap-tooltip.js and bootstrap-popover.js to minimize the footprint.  But I just want it to work and I'm not concerned about file size.  Isn't popover and tooltip included in the bootstrap.js file?

Comment: No, the popover is considered a plugin (modal, tooltips, collapse, etc), so it's not included in the main bootstrap.js file. You could add the popover code to bootstrap.js or use minify to compress multiple javascript files to minimize the footprint?  http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#javascript

Comment: I don't really care about the footprint.  I'm just trying to get it to work right this first time.

Comment: Maybe you could post more of your code, so we can help you "get it to work"?

Comment: What is this: rel="popover"?  That wasn't mentioned in the documentation, although they do mention rel="tooltip".

Comment: Using the rel attribute, it's easy to target all of the tooltips (or popovers) on a single page, like so `$('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip()`, here is another good reference to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436231/tooltips-with-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that I think I had my call to popover above  bootstrap.js.  That's because there were some things that I wanted to do before bootstrap was called, like $('table').addClass('table table-striped table-bordered table-hover');

Comment: Sorry a bit late for the party. Add the tooltip.js before popover.js, that did the trick for me.

Comment: @ews2001 Has this changed with Bootstrap 3? There is a note that it needs to be included manually, yet it also says the bootstrap.js/bootstrap.min.js include all the plugins by default.

Comment: @ZAD-Man - Plugins can be included individually (using Bootstrap's individual *.js files), or all at once (using bootstrap.js or the minified bootstrap.min.js) - taken from this page: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Answer (score 11):

The version of **bootstrap.js** which is included in [the download found on the project's homepage](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/bootstrap.zip) already includes all the plugins compiled into it.  That includes **bootstrap-tooltip.js** and **bootstrap-popover.js**.

`Popover` is the constructor object for the jQuery plugin, but you should not need to instantiate that directly.

The plugin will extend jQuery, adding the method `$.fn.popover()`, which when called will create an instance of a Popover object and attach it to the element you selected.  That object can be accessed on your element (say, `id="elem"`) using `$('#elem').data('popover')`.

Here is a simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/Br4Zg/) that demonstrates one way to create a popup, basically using what you had in the OP, `$('#elem').popover()`.

---

**Update:** [JSFiddle with Bootstrap v.3](http://jsfiddle.net/Br4Zg/620/)

Answer (score 4):

Why popover and tooltip don't work in bootsrap?

The answer is popover or tooltip initializing code `$("#myButton").popover();` should be place under `<script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>;` and 
 `<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`.

Like the following procedure. I think will be ok.

```
<button type="button" id="myPopover" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-original-title="" title="">
      Popover on Right
</button>

<script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      $('#myButton').tooltip();
      $('#myPopover').popover();
</script>
```