# Dealing with non-semantic uses of "rel" in RDFa

Tags: html, semantic-web, rdfa

I use RDFa to add linked data to my webpage.  I also occasionally use the `rel` attribute in various tags for non-semantic purposes, such as triggering a javascript tooltip.  I am wondering the there is something I can do to distinguish the uses.

For instance, I have RDFa around my social network icons like so:

```
<a rel="foaf:account" alt="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/cboettig"><i class="icon-twitter" rel="tooltip" title="follow me on twitter (reading, discussing)"></i></a> 

<a rel="foaf:account" alt="github" href="https://github.com/cboettig"><i class="icon-github" rel="tooltip" title="follow me on Github (code, research)"></i></a>
```

Where `rel` in the anchor tag is used semantically but `rel` the icon tags is used by twitter-bootstrap javascript to add a tooltip.  Magically, in this example, tools such as http://any23.org intelligenty ignore the rel in the icon.  However, when encountering a `rel="tooltip"` in a span element (used to add a tooltip to a button):

```
<span rel="tooltip" title="switch to dark theme">
   <a onclick="switch_style('dark');" class="btn btn-mini"></a> 
</span>
```

This creates an mostly meaningless ntriple such as:

```
<http://any23.org/tmp/> <http://any23.org/tmp/tooltip> <http://any23.org/tmp/> .
```

Of course it's not a huge problem, but I'm not sure why this happens with the span elements and not the other examples, or how to avoid it.

Comment: Related question for a *valid* (hence no duplicate) use of the `rel` attribute: [Rich Snippets: rel=“nofollow” and RDFa](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25488662/1591669)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always a good idea to avoid non-semantic uses of attributes, especially `rel`.
One way to avoid this is to use a class (perhaps `class="tooltip"`) instead of a `rel`.

Comment: okay, good point, that's a simple solution to my problem.  I'm still a bit puzzled how to explain the behavior above where `rel` is only sometimes recognized as semantic by Apache's http://any23.org?

Comment: For reasons that I don't understand, using class instead of rel destroys the display of the icons (whether class is added to a span around them, or directly to the icon).

Comment: Never mind, my problems were caused because "tooltip" class is defined elsewhere in twitter-bootstrap, I simply need a unique class name.