# Rich Snippets: rel="nofollow" and RDFa

Tags: html, rel, rdfa, google-rich-snippets

I'm using [Rich Snippets](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/99170?hl=en&ref_topic=4600154) to markup my content according to the collections on [schema.org](http://schema.org/). I am using [RDFa Lite](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-lite/) to do so and am now having a problem with the `rel` attribute. Some of my links do have the `rel="nofollow"` attribute/value. As RDFa Lite is a subset of RDFa, the `rel` attribute gets recognised as additional markup. Please see [this upload to Google's Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=uploaded:800501754b4e210a2fb575c97d2fd493) for the extracted data for the following markup:

```
<div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="SportsTeam">
  <span property="name">San Francisco 49ers</span>
  <div property="member" typeof="OrganizationRole">
    <div property="member" typeof="http://schema.org/Person">
      <span property="name">Joe Montana</span>
    </div>
    <span property="startDate">1979</span>
    <span property="endDate">1992</span>
    <span property="namedPosition">Quarterback</span>
   <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.google.com/">A Paid Link</a>
</div>
```

The problem is of course, that the *Paid Link* shouldn't appear in the structured markup. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: How strict is the requirement of using RDFa? Wouldn't microdata (e.g. http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=uploaded:8005017622991458aa89ac7e7ba39b5e) be the better option in this case?

Comment: Thanks, @IlyaStreltsyn  - microdata would be the fallback option if it can't be done with RDFa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to use prefixes for your Schema.org usage. Because the [RDFa Core Initial Context](http://www.w3.org/2011/rdfa-context/rdfa-1.1) defines `schema` for `http://schema.org/`, you can even use it without specifying it in a `prefix` attribute first:

```html
<div typeof="schema:SportsTeam">
  <span property="schema:name">San Francisco 49ers</span>
  <div property="schema:member" typeof="schema:OrganizationRole">
    <div property="schema:member" typeof="schema:Person">
      <span property="schema:name">Joe Montana</span>
    </div>
    <span property="schema:startDate">1979</span>
    <span property="schema:endDate">1992</span>
    <span property="schema:namedPosition">Quarterback</span>
   <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.google.com/">A Paid Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I've tried this before with no success. Your provided code validates however, the strange thing is that this stops working as soon as you add the vocab="http://schema.org/" attribute.

Comment: @msparer: Yes, `vocab` defines a vocabulary that can be used without any prefix. Because of that, "nofollow" is considered to be part of the vocabulary. So the solution is *not* to use `vocab`. Use the `prefix` attribute instead. But, described in my answer, it’s optional for Schema.org (and the other vocabularies defined in the RDFa Core Initial Context). -- In an [answer on Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/67264/17633) I made three short examples about `vocab` vs. `prefix` vs. Intial Context.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an empty `vocab=""` on (or around) the elements that use `rel` for purposes outside of RDFa. Like:

```
<div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="SportsTeam">
  <span property="name">San Francisco 49ers</span>
  <div property="member" typeof="OrganizationRole">
    <div property="member" typeof="http://schema.org/Person">
      <span property="name">Joe Montana</span>
    </div>
    <span property="startDate">1979</span>
    <span property="endDate">1992</span>
    <span property="namedPosition">Quarterback</span>
   <a vocab="" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.google.com/">A Paid Link</a>
</div>
```

(Also note that you can use custom (non-URI) `rel` values alongside RDFa in HTML if you just add a `property` on the same element (this makes an RDFa processor ignore the `rel`, as defined in [extension 7 of RDFa 1.1 in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-in-html/#additional-rdfa-processing-rules)). E.g. by adding `property="author"` next to `rel="me"`.)

Comment: Even using `<a vocab rel="nofollow" `