# How do I implement bootstrap tooltips?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How do I get this think up and running? The bootstrap site was a little vague on what to actually do. I want tooltips to pop up when someone hovers over a link on my site.

Comment: I am not sure which bootstrap site you were referring to, they have fairly good documentation and examples provided in their website to get you started and more. http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips

Answer (score 2):

First:

```
<a href="#" class="link" data-original-title="first tooltip">Hover me for a tooltip</a>
```

Then:

```
$('.link').tooltip()
```

See [Tooltips with Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436231/tooltips-with-twitter-bootstrap).