# Twitter bootstrap tooltip is not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing following error while I am trying to use Twitter bootstrap ToolTip.

Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on tooltip prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'show'

Javascript code is :

$("#exclamation-sign").tooltip('show');

Comment: this is the html code 
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip on top" id="exclamation-sign">
Tooltip on top
</a>

Comment: You need to initialise the tooltip before using `show`, ie `$('#exclamation-sign').tooltip({...});`

Comment: Check this link. Might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436231/tooltips-with-twitter-bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-usage), you need to initialize the tooltips before calling methods on them.

So you need to do, for example

```
$("#exclamation-sign").tooltip({ 'animation': true, 'title': 'My Tooltip' });
```

To initialize it. The `options` are described in the table right there in the documentation.

Then when you're ready,

```
$("#exclamation-sign").tooltip('show');
```